# Create GeoTIFF from JPG and JFW files with gdal

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, gdalwarp, gdal-translate

I have a JPG image and the corresponding geospatial information on a JFW [wolrd file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file) in a ETRS89 geodesical system and UTM coordinates (EPSG:25830)

```
5.0000000000
0.0000000000
0.0000000000
-5.0000000000
484752.5000000000
4811767.5000000000
```

I want to create a GeoTIFF on a SRS EPSG:4326 and extract the edge lat/lon coordinates [ulx uly lrx lry]. I am using the folowing command without success which maybe requires to do a warp before (although I don't think so because line 2 and 3 are null on JFW file), and I do not know how to extract the edge values on that projection.

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -a_srs EPSG:4326 -projwin 0 0 [width_jpg] [height_jpg] [from_file_jpg] [to_file_tif]
```

Does someone know how to do it? It is necessary to define width and height of image if I am using the whole image?

**EDIT**

The code used to display the tile is the following one:

```
//WMS overlay
var format = 'image/png8';
var tiled = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
           "Show Layer", "http://<IPaddress>:8080/geoserver/" + workSpace + "/wms",
           {
               LAYERS: layerName,
               STYLES: '',
               TRANSPARENT: true,
               VERSION: '1.3.0',
               format: format,
               tiled: true
           },
           {
               sphericalMercator: true,
               buffer: 0,
               displayOutsideMaxExtent: true,
               isBaseLayer: false,
               opacity: 1.0,
               yx: { 'EPSG:4326': true }
           }
);
map.addLayer(tiled);
```

Comment: What happens when you run the command?

Comment: First thing, rename the .JFW into .JGW (or WLD. which is generic for GDAL). Extrension of .JFW is for image file named as `*.J*F`, in your case it probable means JFIF. Second, your image can't be in EPSG:4326 with those corner coordinates `484752.5000000000 4811767.5000000000` and therefore assigning projection without warping is wrong. Easiest way for getting the corner coordinates is to run gdalinfo. But rename the worldfile first.

Comment: @user30184 you are right. I had the name wrong. And about second point, I was trying to have a GeoTiff with EPSG:4326 SRS but as my image is in EPSG:25830 first I have to translate it and then warp to the new SRS that I was looking for. So the correct commands are: `gdal_translate -of GTiff -a_srs EPSG:25830 [from_file_jpg] [to_file_tif]` and later use gdalwarp

Comment: Or give the source srs in the command `gdalwarp -of GTiff -s_srs EPSG:25830 -t_srs EPSG:4326 input.jpg output.tif`

Comment: However, something that I have checked is that when using OpenLayers to show the layer, when I add the layer it doesn't give error if "yx" attribute is defined EPSG:25830 or EPSG:4326, which is strange because they are different.

Comment: Show the code you use for adding the layer.